# How to cast an Object at runtime in Java when a button is clicked

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors

So I need to know how to cast an parent class to a subclass during runtime (or some other way to point to one of 4 tools available). I have a paint program with 4 tools that are subclassed from my parent tool class "DrawingTool" class. I have a field in my class that extends JPanel for my "canvas" to hold myCurrentTool that will need to change based on the JToggleButton the user currently has selected. I am setting it up so my Action Listener changes to the correct tool when the button is selected. So when a specific button is active the paint method will be calling on that field and it needs to use the overridden methods for whatever specific subclass it should be referencing. I have tried myCurrentTool = myTool, no go. Cant figure out how to cast it without a compile error (hopefully I just don't know the syntax for this.

Any suggestions would be great. Here are some snippets of code. My code is separated into 9 different classes so this is little relevant chunks from wherever.

```
public DrawingAction(final String theName, final Icon theIcon,
                      final DrawingTool theTool, final int theKey) {
    super(theName, theIcon);
    putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, theName + " background");
    putValue(Action.SELECTED_KEY, true);
    putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, theKey);
    myTool = theTool;

}

...
     myDrawingActions `enter code here`= new ArrayList<DrawingAction>();
            myDrawingActions.add(new DrawingAction("Pencil", new ImageIcon("icons\\pencil.gif"),
                                                   new PencilTool(), KeyEvent.VK_L));
            myDrawingActions.add(new DrawingAction("Line", new ImageIcon("icons\\line.gif"),
                                                   new LineTool(), KeyEvent.VK_L));
            myDrawingActions.add(new DrawingAction("Rectangle",
                                                   new ImageIcon("icons\\rectangle.gif"),
                                                   new RectangleTool(), KeyEvent.VK_R));
            myDrawingActions.add(new DrawingAction("Ellipse", new ImageIcon("icons\\ellipse.gif"),
                                                   new EllipseTool(), KeyEvent.VK_E));
```

...

```
public void paintComponent(final Graphics theGraphics) {
    super.paintComponent(theGraphics);
    final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) theGraphics;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                         RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(myLineThickness));
    g2.setColor(myColor);
    g2.draw(myCurrentTool.draw());
}
```

...

```
/**
 * Instance of the Line Drawing Tool.
 */
private LineTool myLine;

/**
 * Instance of Rectangle Tool.
 */
private RectangleTool myRectangle;

/**
 * Instance of Ellipse Tool.
 */
private EllipseTool myEllipse;

/**
 * Instance of Pencil Tool.
 */
private PencilTool myPencil;

/**
 * Holds the currently selected tool.
 */
private DrawingTool myCurrentTool;
```

Comment: Swing, `paint()`, `paintComponent()`, and 'when a button is clicked' are completely irrelevant. There is a typecasting syntax. There's an example of it in your `paintComponent()` method. What is your *actual* problem?

Comment: And what is the error message from the compiler, and which line does it refer to?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: `myDrawingActions `enter code here`= new ArrayList<DrawingAction>();`  Well that would cause a compiler error.  Please take more care using code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Well subclasses can fit perfectly into parent classes, but not vice versa. You are probably trying to put an unrelated Object into another.

**Original:**

You might want to refactor your code instead.
If I understand you correctly you want to cast dynamically to runtime? This is pretty easy using reflection, but I would do it diffrently:

You just get the ID(The String you use in the constructor) from your DrawingAction and use these as a Key in a map `Map<String, MyClass> tools;`.

MyClass is just an Interface with Methods you might want to notify on current events.

For Example:

`public void onButtonClicked(Button b, int x, int y);`

You do not need any casting at all this way, using a dummy abstract class implementing all interface methods you might simply change your class extensions and method names.